# why ingress nginx cannot proxy grpc when client using insecure?

Tags: nginx, grpc, tls1.2, nginx-ingress, grpc-go

path: `go-client --> ingress-nginx --> grpc pod`

Because all the traffic is in our private network, so we didn't buy a public Certificate, rather we use a self-signed certificate. What happened is that the first code below worked well, but the second failed. I don't know why, and I want to know what the `insecure` exactly means.

code that worked well:

```golang
    cert, _ := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile("./example.pem", "example.com")
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(
        ctx,
        "example.com:443",
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(cert),
        grpc.WithBlock(),
    )
```

code that received 400 bad request

```golang
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(
        ctx,
        "example.com:443",
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithBlock(),
    )
```

nginx access log for bad request

```
"PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400
```

ingress yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts: example.com
    secretName: example-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo/bar
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: grpc-svc
          port:
            name: grpc-port
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `insecure` provides an implementation of the `credentials.TransportCredentials` interface which disables transport security. More specifically, it does not perform any TLS handshaking or use any certificates.

gRPC requires that the user pass it some credentials when attempting to create the `ClientConn`. If your deployment does not use any certificates and you know that it is secure (based on whatever reasons), then the `insecure` package will be your friend. But if you are using self-signed certificates, they are still certificates and a TLS handshake needs to happen here. So, in this case, you should continue using the code that you have mentioned at the top of your question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer! It is, and finally I solve it..

Comment: There're actually two concepts: insecure and insecure_skip_verify. because most of the docs don't clarify their differences, it may confusing people like me. Insecure means DONOT use tls at all, so grpc will use h2c underneath. But if grpc still using h2 rather than h2c, it requires tls. When using tls, insecure_skip_verify means client DONOT VERIFY the certificate it received, just believe in it. insecure_skip_verify will make tls not safe any more in public network env, so just use it in test or make sure you know what you're doing